# How do I check if a surface is ruled?

Tags: geometry, smooth-manifolds, surfaces

Let $\varphi: (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}) \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ with $\varphi(t,s)=(\cos\ t-s\ \sin\ t, \sin\ t + s\ \cos\ t, s)$.
I have to find the maximum open set $U$ for which $\varphi$ is "ruled surface".
Unfortunately I don't know the exact english term so I'll try to explain, I want that:

- $\varphi \in \mathscr{C}^{\infty}(U)$, and it's true $\forall\  U$
- $\varphi$ is injective, and it's true only if $s=\pm1$
- $\mathrm{rank}(J_{\varphi}(x, y))$ is maximum (i.e 2) $\forall\ (x,y) \in U$, and it's true $\forall U$

This is the definition of "surface" (the literal translation of what I mean would be "simple sheet of surface"). So I can say that $U$ is a "surface" for $U=(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})\times\left\{\pm1\right\}$ and it's the maximum open set.

Now the problem is: how can I check that this "surface" is ruled too? I know the definition but I have no idea how to apply it.

Comment: If you fix a point $p = \varphi(t_0,s_0)$ in your surface, consider the line $L(s) = \phi(t_0,s)$.

Comment: So have I to check that $\forall\ p_{0} \in \varphi(U)\ \exists\ s\ |\ L_{p_{0}}(s) \subset \varphi(U)$ i.e. that for every fixed point in the surface there is another point for which the line generated by the two points is contained in the surface. How can i check that?

Comment: @nutria: When you write, "$\varphi$ is injective, and it's true if and only if $s = \pm1$", do you mean "$\varphi$ is injective" is the condition in the definition, and you're _asserting_ that in this example "$\varphi$ is injective iff $s = \pm1$"? (If so, I'm not sure how you come to that conclusion. First, a mapping is either injective or not; there's no contingency on values of $s$. Second, your mapping $\varphi$ _is injective_ in the set $U$.)

Comment: You're right, I meant that the $U$ I found is the maximum open for which $\varphi$ restricted to $U$ Is injective. But I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: In this example, it may help to write
$$
\varphi(t, s) = (\cos t, \sin t, 0) + s(-\sin t, \cos t, 1).
$$

Comment: I understood your hint but I'm not sure how to apply It. You say that for every $p_{0}=\varphi(t_{0},s_{0}) \in \varphi(U)$ it lie on the line generated moving $s\in\mathbb{R}$ that Is contained in $\varphi(U)$. The only problem Is the $U$ I found forcing the injectivity Is not $(something) \times \mathbb{R}$ so $s$ is not free ti move to generate the entire line.

Comment: The mapping $\varphi$ is injective on $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}) \times \mathbf{R}$, i.e., for $|t| < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $s$ real; can you please clarify why it seems otherwise?

Comment: I forced $\varphi(t,s)=\varphi(t',s') \implies (t,s)=(t',s')$. If $\varphi(t,s)=\varphi(t',s')$ then $(\cos t -s\sin t, \sin t + s\cos t, s)=(\cos t' -s'\sin t', \sin t' + s'\cos t', s')$ so necessary condition for the injectivity is that $s=s$. Now I have the system$(\cos t -s\sin t, \sin t + s\cos t)=(\cos t' -s\sin t', \sin t' + s\cos t')$, with some calculations I obtain that $s$ must be $\pm1$ otherwise $t\neq t'$.
Maybe I mistaken something with the calculation, but the method is correct, isn't it?

Comment: The first part ($s = s'$) is correct, but after that you have\begin{align*}\varphi(t, s) - \varphi(t', s) &= (\cos t - \cos t', \sin t - \sin t', 0) + s(\sin t' - \sin t, \cos t - \cos t', 0) \\ &= (0, 0, 0).\end{align*}Since $(\cos t - \cos t', \sin t - \sin t', 0) \cdot (\sin t' - \sin t, \cos t - \cos t', 0) = 0$ for all $t$, you can deduce $(\cos t - \cos t', \sin t - \sin t', 0) = (0, 0, 0)$, so $t = t'$.